# Is Netty.io bootstrap.remoteAddress() thread safe？

Tags: java, netty

I need to issue several connections from different threads. I would like to know if I Bootstrap.remoteAddress() is thread safe?

```
  bootstrap.remoteAddress(host, port);
  bootstrap.connect().addListener(new ConnectionListener(radarInfo, publisher));
OR
  bootstrap.connect(host, port).addListener(new ConnectionListener(radarInfo, publisher));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this from multiple threads use:

```
  bootstrap.connect(host, port).addListener(new ConnectionListener(radarInfo, publisher));
```

Otherwise you could end up to change the remoteAddress before you call connect.